# Boot blocks with "Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device"

Tags: ubuntu, boot, suspend

It seems the common solution to this is to run remove `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and run `update-initramfs -u`.

But it is unclear how you get to that stage.

Can you give a special command to GRUB to ignore the resume for a single boot? Or is there a different trick to get past the blocking?

Comment: As of 22.04 LTS this no longer blocks boot, but it does pause for something like 30s and then prints "Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device" if you are watching the console.

Comment: Also, am not sure whether the fix is to remove or just to fix that file. Keep in mind that the reason this happens is that the swap device set in that file is not available at boot.

Comment: worked fine for me in my situation https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470944/ubuntu-22-04-lts-start-up-message-check-which-delays-boot/1471802

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is "a special command", more specifically *a Linux kernel boot option*.

[A lot of kernel boot options are available for various purposes.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)

To skip the attempt to resume from a configured suspend/resume disk/partition (usually a swap partition):

Interrupt GRUB by pressing any key, then press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the currently-selected boot entry, find the line starting with the word `linux` and add `noresume` as a separate word to the end of that line.

This change will not persist: it will take effect for this one boot only. For a persistent change, use the instructions you mentioned in the question.

Comment: You can also add the `noresume` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 10):

A better answer than removing it is to fix it.

If you have a dedicated swap partition, use the `blkid` command to find its UUID.

Then copy this (select, press Ctrl+Shift+C in the terminal window), edit the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file, make sure it has the correct UUID (select the old one, delete it, press Ctrl+Shift+V to paste).

Save it.

Rerun

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot.

Comment: It is a good answer to a different question. Here the question is for the situation how to get the machine to boot to actually *get* to the stage where you can run `blkid`.

Comment: They could always run it from a live USB medium.

Comment: That would be an answer to the question - but a poor one. telcoM's answer is bang on target.

Comment: Interesting. I think "here is how to fix this" is a **better** answer than "here is how to temporarily bypass the problem", _even if that is what was asked._

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it really does not solve the problem: The server is stuck during boot - waiting for the resume device. In other words: There is no prompt to run `blkid` at. Your solution requires physical access, a free USB-port, reconfiguration of BIOS to allow boot from USB, a USB-stick with an image with the needed drivers for the server, and manual decryption of the needed encrypted drives. All of these issues complicate a situation that can be solved by simply adding `noresume` to the boot option.

Comment: You make many assumptions. I see no evidence that they are true. Is it a server? Is it remote? If we are talking ssh access or something how does one get to GRUB? Are the disk(s) encrypted? Why no free USBs? Why wouldn't they have or make a boot medium? You propose a temporary workaround; I have no problem with that. I am proposing a fix. These things are not the same.

Comment: Nope. You are the one making the assumptions. The accepted answer works no matter what. I suggest we let the voters decide if your answer is better than the accepted. Agree?

Comment: If it matters that much to you, sure.

Comment: alternative to noresume:  RESUME=none

Answer (score 0):

Since this is one of the first results when searching "ubuntu 20.04 gave up waiting for suspend/resume" on Google, I should mention that before trying to tinker with `initramfs`to solve the problem,    the first step to solve the
"Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device" issue should be changing the drive mode to AHCI in the BIOS settings, as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1334297/1769716).
After changing this, my Ubuntu booted smoothly.

Answer (score -2):

you have to update your grub config and remove swap info (`resume=UUID=7e4723c7-...`) from `/etc/default/grub` then update grub `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Note that the user in question is unable to get into their system to edit that file.